# Displaying multiple exception messages in PHP

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

So I'm making this login-app, and I've got troubles displaying the correct error-messages upon register. I want all the exceptions to be thrown and not just one exception in a "`try...catch`"-method.

So this is the setup:

```
// EXTENDED EXCEPTION CLASSES
class AException extends Exception {

  public function __construct($message = null, $code = 0) {
      echo $message;
  }
}
class BException extends Exception {

  public function __construct($message = null, $code = 0) {
      echo $message;
  }
}

// INDEX.PHP

try {

    $register = new RegisterController();

} catch (AException | BException $e) {

  $e->getMsg();
}
```

I have several factors that may trigger the exception, and I would like all the exceptions to be triggered and captured e.g. if the register form was posted empty, there should be one exception for username being empty, another exception for password being empty etc..

```
class RegisterController {
    public function __construct() {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $this->checkUserInput();
        $this->checkPassInput();
    }
}

//... executing code

private function checkUserInput() {
    if (strlen($_POST['username']) < 3) { // check character length bigger than 3
        throw new \AException("Username has too few characters.");
    }
}

private function checkPassInput() {
    if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 3) { // check character length bigger than 3
        throw new \BException("Password has too few characters.");
    }
}
}
```

So, how do I make my "`try...catch`"-method echo both the thrown exceptions? Is it possible?

Right now only the first thrown exception-message is displayed, so I guess I need to find some way for the script to continue after an exception has been thrown...

P.S. To clarify further: if a register form is posted with empty input-fields e.g. both username and password input is empty, I want the code to echo two exception-messages, both "Username has too few characters." and "Password has too few characters.".

Comment: This is not how exceptions are working. You are trying to use exceptions for flow control, that is a "no go". Exceptions are meant to terminate an execution right away. You probably want to register "incidents" into some log facility or catalog where you can read them from one back in the calling scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how the try/catch mechanism is supposed to work. It is not meant to report notices to end users, but to programmatically take action if an undesired situation occurs.

What you want is a simple form validation:

```
class RegisterController {
    public $errors = [];

    public function __construct() {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $this->checkUserInput();
        $this->checkPassInput();
    }

    private function checkUserInput() {
        if (strlen($_POST['username']) < 3) { // check character length bigger than 3
            $this->errors[] = "Username has too few characters.";
        }
    }

    private function checkPassInput() {
        if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 3) { // check character length bigger than 3
            $this->errors[] = "Password has too few characters.";
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use something like:

```
$register = new RegisterController();
if (!empty($register->errors)) {
    foreach ($register->errors as $error) {
        echo '<div class="error">' . $error . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing the login-method for a school project, and it was requested to use the exception as a message to the user. Guess the login-module isn't suppose to be for an end user, but maybe another developer. Anyway, your answer led me to the right direction, so I'm going to mark this as the correct answer